# Calling server side method through Breeze

Tags: javascript, breeze

I want to use Breeze API to save my data from client side.

First of all I am fetching data on the server side using Linq Query and storing it in my in-built model/entity (say ProfileData). After that on client side I am using Breeze's executeQuery to fetch data which returns my model (ProfileData).

Now while saving I am storing data in an array of object on client side (say userData) and on server side I have method called **SaveProfileData(int userId, UserProfile data) {}**, where UserProfile contians properties stored in userData of JS.

So, how do I call SaveProfileData of server side and pass parameters to it? I've tried below code but nothing is happening.

```
var so = new breeze.SaveOptions({ allowConcurrentSaves: true, resourceName: "SaveProfileData" });

manager.saveChanges(userData, so)
   .then(function (data) {})
   .fail(function (e) {});
```

Comment: Is userData (on the client) an array of ProfileData entities?  That is what [saveChanges](http://breeze.github.io/doc-js/api-docs/classes/EntityManager.html#method_saveChanges) would expect.  If you inspect the network traffic (using the Network tab of your browser's F12 dev tools), what is being sent?

Comment: Sorry for late reply Steve. While getting data I am using ProfileData model, but while saving I am using UserProfile model. So, do you mean that while saving also I should use ProfileData model? Also, if I pass array of ProfileData model from client side, then on server side what should the parameter look like, because now I get error that **"The 'entities' parameter  is optional or it  must be an array where each element  must be an entity"** even though I am passing array of entity?

Comment: Breeze doesn't seem to think that your objects are entities.  What does your breeze metadata look like?

Comment: My userData looks like this:

var userData = [{
   UserId: 1,
   Name: "ABC",
   Phone: "12345"
}];

And, on server side I am just not getting what parameter to use?

Comment: In your previous comment, userData is not an entity.  It has no entityType defined.  Breeze does not know what it is.  Each [entity](http://breeze.github.io/doc-js/inside-entity.html) must have an entityType, and each entityType must be defined in [metadata](http://breeze.github.io/doc-js/metadata.html).

BTW, what server technology stack are you using?